# Investigate the validity of the argument

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If Tom wears a mask, then he will not be affected by COVID 19.
If Tom does not stay at home, then he will wear a mask.
But he has affected by COVID 19.
Therefore he must have stayed at home.

Comment: And they've been saying that staying at home is safer for you...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this reasoning is that "he will not be affected by COVID-19" is referring to the future, while "he has [been] affected by COVID-19" is referring to the past.  These are not the same thing.

Comment: What is the contrapositive of the first statement?

Comment: is it invalid ?